# I keep getting a ValidationError when trying to add a new object to my MongoDB database using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Hello everyone I've been trying to figure out why my code will not allow me to add a new Developer object to my MongoDB database. Whenever I try I simply get "ValidationError" and I cannot understand why.

**Developer.js Schema**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let developerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        firstName : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        lastName : String
    },
    level: {
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
        enum: ["BEGINNER", "EXPERT"],
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        state: String,
        suburb: String,
        street: String, 
        unit: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Developer', developerSchema);
```

**Code for Developer Insertion in the main server.js file**

```
let addfirstName = req.body.devFirstName;
let addlastName = req.body.devLastName;
let lvl = req.body.devLevelStatus;
let addState = req.body.addressState;
let addSuburb = req.body.addressSuburb;
let addStreet = req.body.addressStreet; 
let addUnit = req.body.addressUnit;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DevelopersWeek7', function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log('Error in Mongoose connection');
    throw err;
}

console.log('Successfully connected');

let addDeveloper = new Developer({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
     name: {
        firstName : addfirstName,
        lastName : addlastName
    },
    level: lvl,
    address: {
        state: addState,
        suburb: addSuburb,
        street: addStreet, 
        unit: addUnit
    }
});

addDeveloper.save(addDeveloper, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Developer successfully Added to DB');
    });
});
```

The variables at the start of the code block are taken from an HTML page.

**HTML PAGE WHERE req.body gets it's value**

```
<html>
<link rel = "stylesheet" src = "colours.css">
<head>
    <h1>
        Add a new Developer
    </h1>
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "/insertDeveloper" method = "POST">
        Developer First Name <br> <input type = text name = "devFirstName"><br>
        Developer Last Name <br>  <input type = text name = "devLastName"><br>
        Level: <br> <select name = "devLevelSelect">
            <option value = "BEGINNER"> Beginner </option>
            <option value = "EXPERT"> Expert </option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Address: State <br> <input type = text name = "addressState"><br>
        Address: Suburb <br>  <input type = text name = "addressSuburb"><br>
        Address: Street <br>  <input type = text name = "addressStreet"><br>
        Address: Unit <br>  <input type = text name = "addressUnit"><br>
        <button href = "/">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: share full error logs

Comment: Here is the result from the Debug Console: 
Successfully connected server.js:71
ValidationError  events.js:183

Comment: It will be great if you can also provide `req.body`.

Comment: I just added it right now

Comment: I have tried your code, its working perfectly fine so there is something wrong with your request body. Just put console.log(req.body); before doing anything and examine that

Comment: Thank you. I just found my problem. I had incorrect Variable names.